# Slide is skiping in swiper with loop: true or without it

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I don't understand what's wrong here.
but when I want to make the next slide active, this slide is skipped
loop: true is also not working correctly
Also, I want to add the ability to click on a slide and make it active

```
new Swiper(".mySwiperPhotos", {
    grabCursor: true,

    mousewheel: true,
    keyboard: true,

    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    spaceBetween: 16,
    initialSlide: 1,

    loop: true,

    breakpoints: {
    600: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        slidesPerGroup: 2,
        spaceBetween: 37,
    },
    },
});
```

I tried to do this, but it didn't work out

```
let mySwiperPhotos = new Swiper(".mySwiperPhotos", {
    grabCursor: true,
    mousewheel: true,
    keyboard: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    spaceBetween: 16,
    initialSlide: 1,
    loop: true,
    loopAdditionalSlides: 1,

    breakpoints: {
      600: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        slidesPerGroup: 2,
        spaceBetween: 37,
      },
    },
  });

mySwiperPhotos.on('click', function() {
    var activeSlideIndex = mySwiperPhotos.clickedIndex;
    if (activeSlideIndex !== mySwiperPhotos.activeIndex) {
        mySwiperPhotos.slideToLoop(activeSlideIndex);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `slideToClickedSlide` (false by default) API option (No need for any custom code).

> **slideToClickedSlide**: Set to true and click on any slide will produce
> transition to this slide

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slideToClickedSlide